# Total Number of Rows Having Different Row Values by Group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {
    'group1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
    'group2': ['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xy', 'xy'],
    'num1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3],
    'num2': [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 7],
}
pd.DataFrame(data))
```

[image]

I want to get the total number of rows that have different row records by `group1` and `group2`. A count means for a unique combination of `num1` and `num2` by `group1` and `group2`, hence if there are multiple records of the same values then it still counts as one.

For instance, there are 5 records for `group1 = A & group2 = xx`.
It should output 2 because:

- the first 3 rows of `num1` and `num2` are identical and
- the 4th and 5th row (`num1 = 1 & num2 = 3`) is another duplicate.

The last two rows is another group (`group1 = B & group2 = xy`). These two records have a different num1 and num2 values so it should output 2.

Expected outcome:

[image]

My attempt so far:

```
df[df.groupby(['group1', 'group2'])[['num1', 'num2']].transform(lambda x, y: x.nunique() > 1 & y.nunique() > 1)]
```

Comment: Couple of issues. 1: You forgot to show your attempt. 2: You didn't formally define the rules, so no one can actually answer your question based on your examples. For instance, how should it be scored if you add another row with Axx13? Do both of the Axx groups count as 1? What if there's a third Axx12 row? Is that a 3 or a 1?

Comment: Sorry I reflected your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) + [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.drop_duplicates()[['group1', 'group2']].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
group1  group2
A       xx        2
B       xy        2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

As a new column:

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['group1', 'group2']), 'count'] = (
    df.drop_duplicates()[['group1', 'group2']].value_counts().values
)
```

Or:

```
df['count'] = (df.assign(unique=~df.duplicated())
                 .groupby(['group1', 'group2'])
                 ['unique'].transform('sum')
                 .mask(df.duplicated(subset=['group1', 'group2']))
              )
```

Output:

```
  group1 group2  num1  num2  count
0      A     xx     1     2    2.0
1      A     xx     1     2    NaN
2      A     xx     1     2    NaN
3      A     xx     1     3    NaN
4      A     xx     1     3    NaN
5      B     xy     4     6    2.0
6      B     xy     3     7    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if I understand you correctly. But you can try:

```
groups = df.groupby(['group1', 'group2'])[["num1", "num2"]].apply(lambda d: (d.groupby(["num1", "num2"]).size() > 1).sum())
```

This does the following:

1. generate a grouped dataframe by `['group1', 'group2']`, these are the things we gonna evaluate group-wise
2. to each of these groups apply the operation that groups the numeric values `["num1", "num2"]`, and check for the size of these groups, such that there is more than `1` element in it
3. taking the `.sum()` of a boolean `df` basically counts the `True` values, hence the number where our "group-size-checking" resulting in a count greater than `1`

Comment: This correctly gives 2 for A xx group but not for B xy it gives 0. It should return 2

Comment: Your question was edited afterwards. However, if it should simply count sizes of all subgroups regardless of subgroup size you could try: `groups = df.groupby(['group1', 'group2'])[["num1", "num2"]].apply(lambda d: d.groupby(["num1", "num2"]).size().count())`

Comment: This is a quite inefficient way of doing this, `groupby` is rather expensive